# Error : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL

Tags: java, http

I'm new to development and I'm on IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 (Community Edition).
For example, I want to connect and retrieve the web page: [www.carrefour.fr](http://www.carrefour.fr)
I have the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.carrefour.fr/
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1919)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
at Main.main(Main.java:111)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have searched a lot on the internet and tested but it does not solve the problem. How to correct the problem?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder content=new StringBuilder();
        // Use try and catch to avoid the exceptions
        try
        {
            URL url=new URL("https://www.carrefour.fr"); // creating a url object

            // First set the default cookie manager.
            CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));  

            URLConnection urlConnection=url.openConnection(); // creating a urlconnection object

            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0 Unique/100.7.9656.57");        

            // wrapping the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String line;
            
            // reading from the urlconnection using the bufferedreader
            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                content.append(line+"\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(content.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: "I have searched a lot on the internet" => From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403): "The HTTP 403 is an HTTP status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden."

Comment: I am wondering why do you have comments like `x=y; //assigning y to x` :)\

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose On Firefox or Google Chrome it works correctly, I have no problem

Comment: @Antoniossss The comments, are the "solutions" that I found on the internet but which did not work, I left them to show you what I have already tested

Comment: I'm just saying that those comments have no value as they are describing obvious code and are literally a noise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's no wrong with your code, but the website does not want people to run crawlers on it.

See https://www.carrefour.fr/robots.txt
See also [Robots exclusion standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

Comment: One possible solution (but not promised to work): open the website manually, check the request headers, and try adding some to your crawler's header by `setRequestProperty`

Comment: As I said in my message, I'm a little new in the devellopement.
What do you mean by: check request headers ?

Comment: Assume that you uses Chrome, plz open the website, then press `F12` to open the developer tool. There will be several tabs, select `Network` then refresh the page, you will see lots of packages.

Comment: Then select a package, click on it, and you can see the `Headers` tab, go to the end of that page, you may find several `Request Headers`, please try adding some of the headers to your java code, which may help but not always can help.